# string.Format in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to simulate the C# `string.Format()` in JS.

For this, I have an object called `string` and a function called `Format()` passing as parameter, in a variadic function, a string with its placeholders and also its values.

An example should be:

```
string.Format("{0} - {1}", "Hello", "World");
```

that must return me `Hello - World`.

Although, it gives me just "{undefined} - {undefined}". I'm using global modifier to get all, but it doesn't works.

---

```
var string = {
    Format: function() {
        var text = arguments[0];
        for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var result = text.replace(/([0-9]+)/g, arguments["$1"]);
        }
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

Where is my error?

Comment: a. The first index is 0, not 1. b. You should replace the whole `{..}` thing, not just the number. c. you never modify `text`, you never do anything with `result`, you never return anything. d. I can't even imagine what you think `arguments["$1"]` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always starting from the initial string (ignoring the previous replacements) and there are parts of you're function where it's unclear how it's supposed to work.

Here's a working implementation based on your general idea :

```
var string = {
  Format: function() {
    var args = arguments,
        result = args[0].replace(/([0-9]+)/g, function(s) { return args[+s+1] });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

It logs `"{Hello} - {World}"`

Now, supposing you don't want to keep the braces and you also want to ensure you only replace numbers between braces, you can do this (without the debug logging) :

```
var string = {
    Format: function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return args[0].replace(/{([0-9]+)}/g, function(s) {
            return args[+s.slice(1,-1)+1]
        });
    }
}
```

It returns `"Hello - World"`